# Android ListView change bg color but leave onclick animation

Tags: android, listview

I have ListView in Android that contains my objects. The background color of each row represents the state of the object, so I want to have different colors for different rows, but I want to have onClick animation. In addition to that, some rows have default bg color so I want to preserve default onClick animation for them.

In ArrayAdapter, if I set background color `getView()` method - animation stops working. 
How can I have both animation and non-standart bg color?

**Update 1**: my getView method looks the following:

```
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {       
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.action_table_row, parent, false);
        }
        if (conditionIsMet(getItem(position)) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f6bcbc"));
        }
``
```

Comment: Can you post your `getView()` code?

Comment: @GiuseppeCriscione added it to the topic

Answer (score 0):

create a drawable : res/drawable/mycolor1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

// onclick
<item android:state_pressed="true">

<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="4sp" />
    <solid
        android:color="your_color" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2sp"
        android:color="your_border_color" />
    <padding android:top="5sp" android:right="5sp"
        android:bottom="5sp" android:left="5sp"/>
</shape>
</item>
// default
<item android:state_enabled="true">

<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="3sp" />
    <solid
//leave it empty if you want default color
       />
    <stroke
        android:width="2sp"
        android:color="your_border_color" />
    <padding android:top="5sp" android:right="5sp"
        android:bottom="5sp" android:left="5sp"/>
</shape>
```

then you set the drawable instead of the color, 
you can set it from the adapter or the row xml.

Comment: how can I know what default animation is used? because I want to preserve it

Answer (score 0):

Change background color in your `onBindViewHolder`

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (conditionIsMet(getItem(position)) {
            holder.yourLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f6bcbc"));
        }
    }
```